# Why is the Unix linker called "ld"

Tags: history

Tried to search the web and couldn't find an answer. It might have something to do with "load", but that doesn't make much sense to me.

Obviously, "ln" was already taken, but where does that "d" come from?

Comment: How would you assertively know that _linking_ appeared before _loading_?

Comment: I wouldn't, and may well be wrong about that.

Comment: But you could be right my dear, see [here](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/1stEdman.html) (linked from [here](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl) (linked from [here](http://www.unix.com/news-links-events-announcements/9380-browsing-unix-source-code-via-web.html) (linked from [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unix+source+code&t=debian)))) that there is already a `ln` as long as the `ar` and `ld` in first edition UNIX ca. 1971. I'm afraid the living authors may be starting to forget this kind of anecdote.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Linkers in Linux were originally called loaders. See [Assembly Language Step-by-Step: Programming with Linux](http://books.google.com/books?id=veMTOpapeZkC&lpg=PT141&ots=_jKLfnCe8M&dq=why%20is%20the%20unix%20linker%20called%20ld&pg=PT141#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Jeff Duntemann:

> #### Linking the Object code File
>
> ...Linux comes with its own linker, called ld. (The name is actually short for "load", and "loader" was what linkers were originally called, in the First Age of Unix, back in the 1970s.)

Comment: Note that the term "loading" is still used - when starting a program it is loaded in some memory area and to quite some degree the same operations as with "linking" happen, not only due to dynamic/runtime linking .. "Linkers and Loaders" by John R. Levine (ISBN: 1558604960) is a good book for the ones who want to know all the details.

Comment: Please, please, please, people, please try to remember that computers and software and operating systems DID exist before Unix was invented.  The term "loader", as in "relocating (or relocatable: both terms were common) linking loader" goes back to LONG before Unix.  I first ran into it in about 1970, and I'd be VERY surprised if there weren't relocating linking loaders in 1960.

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: Which is pretty much what my linked quote says.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The point I was trying to make is that the term "loader" goes back to long BEFORE "the First Age of Unix, back in the 1970s."

Comment: @JohnR.Strohm: I'm not sure that matters.  However, in the interest of being historically precise, feel free to edit in an authoritative reference.

Comment: The other answer has added some interesting counters to this, including PDF links of 1971 UNIX man pages that use *link editor*, not *link loader*.

Answer (score 17):

Because it is "link editor". For example, Solaris and AIX man pages explicitly say so:

- [Solaris `ld` man page](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ld+1)

  > ld - link-editor for object files
- [AIX `ld` man page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/ld.htm)

  > The ld command, also called the linkage editor or binder

In the comment to the question there is an [extremely interesting link](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Dennis_v1/) to 1971 UNIX man pages. There is a `ld` man page, which explicitly states *ld - link editor*, see the [man12.pdf file (page 20)](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Dennis_v1/man12.pdf):

> NAME ld -- link editor

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)#Linkage_editor) mentions that there are different theories, one is "loader" one is "link editor".

Sidenote - amazing, regular expressions already existed in 1971...

Comment: Proof added, extremely easy to find even in internet. Now please provide reason for -1's.

Comment: I didn't vote, so I can't give you any reasons. Others may have felt your answer was too thin on the ground.

Comment: I find this answer better.  ld is definitely link editor or linker as it does not load anything.  ld.so is both linker and loader.

Comment: link to the 1971 man page is lost to bit rot

Comment: The wikipedia page just cites a stackoverflow answer from 2012, which itself does not have a source. I'm tempted to believe, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574354/4225094, which claims "LD is "Link Editor". LE was already used to mean "less or equal" in a shell, likely sh. So, per convention, the conflicting character was moved one character forward in the word being abbreviated."